# Can we define two functions with same name but different parameters?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, c++14

I am confused when we need to define another function we can give it a different name. But on LeetCode discussion, I found a popular post in which there are two functions with same name, but having different parameters.

```
int longestPalindromeSubseq(string s) {
    return longestPalindromeSubseq(0,s.size()-1,s); 
}
int longestPalindromeSubseq(int l, int r, string &s) {
    if(l==r) return 1;
    if(l>r) return 0;  //happens after "aa" 
    return s[l]==s[r] ? 2 + longestPalindromeSubseq(l+1,r-1, s) : 
        max(longestPalindromeSubseq(l+1,r, s),longestPalindromeSubseq(l,r-1, s)); 
}
```

Comment: since your history is javascript, I'd also point out that in javascript it's usually archived by accepting a single parameter object, while in javascript you need to dispatch them be self, in c++ compiler dispatch them to different function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I am confused when we need to define another function we can give it a different name.

The is the one of the most basic feature of C++: function overloading. In C you can't have two functions with the same name, at all. In C++, it's entirely possible as long as the function function signature is different, ie two functions having the same name but different set of parameters.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading

Comment: "_r even the same set of parameters but different types_" - You can't have two functions where the only difference is their type. If the parameters are the same, the cv-qualification or ref-qualifiers must differ.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I agree that was confusing. What I intended to say was to have the same set of parameters names but the combined parameters types should still be unique for each function. That comment probably adds more confusion and so been removed. As in fact, it's the parameter types that are important, the parameters names are not.

Comment: To add to the confusion: I interpreted "_types_" as the functions types and not the argument types :-) Like `double foo()` and `int foo()` which will not work but `double foo() &` and `int foo() &&` will.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes indeed your interpretation of function type is correct.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at is called "Function overloading" in C++. The c++ compiler creates signatures based on the declaration of the function. You can have entirely different signatures of a function with the same name.

In the example posted by you, the signature changes because of the difference in the parameters passed.

here is what Signature stands for :
*the information about a function that participates in overload resolution (13.3): its parameter-type-list (8.3.5) and, if the function is a class member, the cv-qualifiers (if any) on the function itself and the class in which the member function is declared.*

Answer (score 0):

In a strongly typed language, the parser can (in principle) make the difference between functions with the same name but a different argument list (number and type of the arguments), at function-declaration time as well as function-call time. This is called function overloading and also applies to class methods.

C++ supplies this feature.

---

In some cases, there are ambiguities and the compiler will tell you. In C++ you cannot declare functions that only differ by their return type.